# Open websites in new tab

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

When I am in a sharepoint list. How can I make it so that any links in the list open outside? Thanks!

I have this script to open files in a new location.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("OpenPDFInNewWindow()");
   function OpenPDFInNewWindow() 
    {      
      var aAllLinks = document.links;     
      for(var i=0;i<aAllLinks.length;i++) 
      { 
         var oA = aAllLinks[i]; 
         var sHREF = oA.href.toLowerCase(); 

         if(sHREF.indexOf(".jpg") > 0 || sHREF.indexOf(".pdf") > 0) 
         { 
            oA.onclick=function() 
            { 
            var w=window.open(this.href,'_blank'); 
            if(w) { 
              w.focus(); 
              return false 
            }; 
            return true; 
          } 
         } 
      } 
    } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this blog, mentioned couple of ways to acheive this goal. This is true but valid so far for 2013.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/02/sharepoint-link-list-open-in-new-window_21.html

But may be you will see this issue due to **2013 minimal download strategy** . May be you need to disable it.

Check this solution: http://www.siolon.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-site-navigation-does-not-open-in-new-window/